# Is it possible to have .bashrc outside home directory?

Tags: 11.10, bash, command-line, bashrc

I want to put a .bashrc file in a directory where my application is located, to set up path variables accordingly independent of the location of the directory at the moment. 
At the same time,  I want to be able to run the application right away, without having to `source` a shell file to set the path every time. Therefore I figured I could use `.bashrc` which is executed when the non-login terminal is started.

If I do put it in the proper `.bashrc` in the home directory, I would have to give an absolute path which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to have something like `.bashrc` but not in home directory (ie a shell that is executed when terminal is started?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--rcfile "file"` bash option, that read `"file"` instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

You can create a launcher for gnome-terminal that in turns launch `bash` with that option.

Comment: Hm, but I still want to read ~/.bashrc, I want it to read it and 'file' additionally. Also, giving it 'file' sort of defeats the point since I was hoping to do it location-independent and without giving an absolute path.

Comment: @FSchmidt: for the first request, you can add `. ~/.bashrc` as the first line of `file`. For the second request: how do you think `bash` could find your file, if you do not want to say where is?

Comment: Good question! I was hoping there would be a bash option that tells it to run, for example, any files named '.bashrc' in all subdirectories.